# How much processing time for non-Chinese EB5 Investors?

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

[This](https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/) page mentions that the Processing time for Immigrant Petition by Alien Investor (I-526) at Immigrant Investor Program Office is:

(1) 54 Months to 75 Months for China - mainland born investors

(2) 31.5 Months to 60 Months    All other areas

I am from India, does this mean that I have to wait for at least 31.5 months to get an approval? What does it mean for some investor from Netherlands? Does he have to wait for at least 31.5 months as well, like me?

Also, why is the processing time different for Chinese nationals? I mean this is not a waitlist, is this? This is not a green card queue right? This is simply about processing regardless of any country cap. Country cap comes after the processing and approval.

Comment: The second question is different, and its answer is different.  It should be asked separately.

Comment: @phoog Done! That will be another question.

Comment: The other question has been [posted here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21102/what-makes-us-immigrant-visa-processing-times-different).

Comment: The answer to the questions in the first paragraph are *yes; the same as for someone from India;* and *yes.*  The first question in the second paragraph is the most interesting, and I do not know the answer, which is why I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: @phoog I hopefully found an answer to the second question. [This page](https://eb5affiliatenetwork.com/uscis-introduces-separate-estimated-processing-time-range-for-chinese-eb-5-investors/) doesn't answer the "why" aspect of it, but confirms that there is some vague reason to introduce separate processing time for Chinese nationals.